# AWS API GW Resource Policy document larger than the maximum allowed size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

Trying to whitelist the IP in API GW, we cannot add more IP in the condition source IP

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard}}",
            "Condition" : {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [ "{{sourceIpOrCIDRBlock}}", "{{sourceIpOrCIDRBlock}}" ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "execute-api:/{{stageNameOrWildcard}}/{{httpVerbOrWildcard}}/{{resourcePathOrWildcard}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above policy is there any way we can get the array of IP from s3 bucket or increase the policy document size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Length, in characters, of API Gateway resource policy" can be increased as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html). You can request the limit increase from Service Quotas.